# mongokit and django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm looking for good tutorial or really simple code to integrate mongokit and django

Comment: seems like it's just python code. import and use. pretty simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.peterbe.com/plog/how-and-why-to-use-django-mongokit would seem to cover this. BTW this was the first result on google for search term "mongokit django".